# Does react-native support NSDataDetector?

Tags: ios, cocoa, react-native, nsdatadetector

Is there a way to access Cocoa's [NSDataDetector](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/) from `react-native`?

Something like `UITextView`'s `dataDetectorTypes`?

I want to use it for automatic Address detection, to link to Maps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that NSDataDetector themselves support RN atm. But there are couple of libraries that you might be interested in.

I am not sure my answer will solve your scenario. But I had a requirement of needing to enable text links clickable and phone numbers as well.

**react native html view** - https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview.

This helped me to solve my situation. 
Also have a look at [AutoLinker](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

React Native's [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) component has a dataDetectorProps that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Not exactly— that is for inputting text, I want to use it to decorate text coming from the server, being served in a <Text>.

Comment: @David A multiline TextInput on iOS will be a UITextView. According to Apple's docs: `UITextView supports the display of text using custom style information and also supports text editing. You typically use a text view to display multiple lines of text, such as when displaying the body of a large text document.`. So it can be used for more than inputting text. Ideally you can wrap it in another component that has a better name